# Has a mammalian species that cannot interbreed with another ever been selectively bred in isolation from it so that it can?

Tags: evolution, artificial-selection

Take two mammalian species that cannot interbreed by any means. Has one ever been selectively bred in isolation from the other so that eventually it can?

Comment: Define "cannot". It's quite usual to use techniques like embryo rescue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embryo_rescue in plant breeding in order to create hybrids between species that otherwise couldn't successfully interbreed in nature.  I think that sometimes the resulting hybrids can be fertile with one or both parent species.

Comment: Restating jamesqf comments: What kind of of reproctive isolation barriers are you willing to consider. Two species cannot interbreed if there is a mountain range between them! Two species cannot interbreed if they do not want to mate at the same time of the day (this is a type of pre-zygotic reproductive isolation known in several *Diptera* species for example).

Comment: "Cannot" means "are not able to by any means". I'll amend.

Comment: define breed, some viruses can transfer genetic material between species, so thing we are happy to exploit in genetic engineering.

Comment: "Breed" means "sexually reproduce to produce offspring". I won't add this, because it is obvious. I will, however, change to specify mammals.

Comment: And you are accepting any kind of reproductive barrier? Would moving a species on the other side of a mountain range count?

Comment: For the edited question, and just considering biological barriers like different chromosome counts, I'd suggest that the answer is no, simply because it would take a lot of time and effort (and expense!) for no obvious benefit.  That doesn't mean it's not possible, as shown by a number of distant crosses in plants, where there is obvious economic benefit.  E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%97_Chitalpa

Comment: I'm assuming that the only way we can know if it "can" interbreed with the other species is if it does, whether in domestication or wherever. @jamesqf - I am not sure about that. There are some mysterious things where canines are concerned. [Research paper from 2009](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763232/).